# embedded resource in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, resources

I am trying to create a mvc3 helper dll that contains some embedded resources such as scripts and css files.  I want to access the embedded resource without using the WebResourceAttribute from the System.Web.UI library.  It doesn't seem to belong.

I think a good approach is to create a controller and view to serve the embedded resource.  I am not quite sure on the best way to implement this so that it can be project independent and reusable.

Any suggestions?

Comment: if you'll use controller action to serve these resources, why don't you store them in database?

Comment: My goal is create a dll library that can be reused by other projects.  Database is not an appropriate place to store the resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GetManifestResourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream.aspx) and [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493017%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) action result. But keep in mind that those stylesheets and scripts are not going to be ediable without rebuilding assembly